# RVM Install Error (There is no checksum.. it's not possible to validate it)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

On running the command

```
rvm install 1.9.2    # or 1.9.3 or 2.0.0 all report the same.
```

Im getting the following error:

> There is no checksum for
>   'http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-1.8.25.tgz' or
>   'rubygems-1.8.25.tgz', it's not possible to validate it. If you wish
>   to continue with unverified download add '--verify-downloads 1' after
>   the command.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to update RVM more often:

```
rvm get stable # OR:
rvm get head
```

It will not only update RVM code but also all `ruby` and `rubygems` definitions, including checksums for rubygems.

Answer (score 6):

Ha I just needed to update RubyGems!

```
gem update --system
```